jspdf multiple divs rendering empty
I am using jsPDF and want to generate content from multiple divs. My JavaScript is detecting the divs but is rendering them empty.
Why is that?
Here is my code:
const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'px', 'a4');

var results_divs = window.document.getElementsByClassName('resultclasses');

for (var i = 1; i < results_divs.length; i++) {
    doc.html(window.document.getElementById('resultid' + i), {
        callback: function (doc) {
            resolve();
        },
        margin: [10, 10, 10, 10]
            
    });

    doc.addPage();
}

doc.save('test.pdf');   

Classname is detected, the newest version of jsPDF installed, addpage is executed, tried several variations.

It would be good if you provide complete code representation of the problem - in this example the html/css code is missing.

I found out that pdf.html function cannot be used more than once. So, there is no solution.

Put everything within a div and use data-html2canvas-ignore (on html tag) directive to ignore the ones you don't want.

Yes but I want to make new pages between the divs :(
